# Input to terminal similar to git rebase -i

Tags: shell, editor

I'm writing a CLI application where it would be helpful to ask the user for long form input, where it could be pasted into the terminal.

`git rebase -i` takes input in this exact way, by just opening an editor (in my case neovim) instead of having to present some extra interface. How can I replicate this? It would be extra nice if the editor can also be chosen by the user.

I'm writing in Rust, but assume this would happen through another CLI program.

Answer (score 0):

Usually there are two variables in user's environment, either `EDITOR` or `VISUAL`. If set, both of them will contain command which should be used as default editor. Historically `VISUAL` was intended for modern terminals with advanced features, while `EDITOR` was used for line text editors (like `ed`, `ex`, etc..) over teletype terminal (one which prints results on paper). Nowadays it is debatable which variable should be preferred - most programs, including `git`, still choose `VISUAL` first and fallback to `EDITOR`. If none of those variables is set, you can choose reasonable default editor by yourself.